# How do I move my background down half the speed of my posts

Tags: html, css, blogs

I want to make the background on my blog move slightly every time I scroll down, giving it a 3D effect. I even made a pretty picture to show you exactly what I mean:

[image]

so how would I go about doing this? Say, I move the posts on my blog down 50%. I would want my background to move down about 25%. So the background would move down half of what my posts do. Thanks!

Comment: (js) `bgtop = (scrollTop*-1)/2` ?

Comment: Rough demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/EKsJK/) - that what you're after?

Comment: +1 for the picture. But next time I expect to see some hand drawn circles.

Comment: Stumbled across this in my search for the answer, found a [pure CSS solution via this stack overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37747966/1992129)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial that walks through the process of making a parallax effect without any plugins: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/

Here's the demo: http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/2138_SimpleParallax/Demo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Is smokeyPHP's solution applicable to a div instead of a background image?
So instead of the background image scrolling at a slower speed, make an underlying div (z-index:-1) scroll at a slower speed.

SmokeyPHP's solution][1](http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/EKsJK/)

```
document.addEventListener('scroll',function(e) {
    var newPos = (window.scrollY*-1)/2
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center "+newPos+"px";
});
```

Eddy